# Build target with API level below 14 and v7 appcompat library

Tags: android, gradle, android-appcompat

Having issues with `appcompat-v7` and `compileSdkVersion`, the app build target is `API 10` so I set `compileSdkVersion 10` to compile the code safely, as expected it works well with `support-v4`: the app compiles and runs on API 10 devices.

Then I want to add `appcompat-v7` to dependencies (or replace `v4` with it) and perform clean re-build of the app without any changes at the code or resources, build fails at the `R` generation stage unless the `compileSdkVersion` is set to a higher value.

I understand it as the `v7` library is using some `values` unavailable at `API 10`. It raises the question of how someone can continue to write safe code and use `v7` without need to manually check API level of each variable and method. Is there a way to keep using `v7` (that is claimed to be *"designed to be used with Android 2.1 (API level 7)"*) and `compileSdkVersion 10` ?

Comment: compile and target should be max (19 at this time) just min should be 10 (or 7) ...

Comment: By build target I meant the minimum supported API version which is 10 at this context. Setting `compileSdkVersion` to match `targetSdkVersion` instead of `minSdkVersion` doesn't make sense for  me.

Comment: support libraries are using methods from higher API level or own implementations depends on target device(not targetSdkVersion) ... at compile time they need "android.jar" with those methods ... but at the runtime library checks device API lvl and uses those methods or (as i wrote before) own implementation ...

Comment: I understand that, still can't see any reason to increase `compileSdkVersion` value above `minSdkVersion `. This library is said to support API level 7 after all. Note that the build fails not at the code compilation but at the resources generation stage (`:app:mergeDebugResources`) - the dependency adds `values-v14` to the build and I'd be happy to let the app to use them at runtime not screwing up the app build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently at the newest Intellij version Lint produces errors if the methods form the API above `minSdkVersion` is used (can be enabled/disabled at Preferences-Inspections, expand Android Lint at the list, look for Calling new methods on older versions or use "NewApi" annotation to suppress the error if needed).

That'll have to do until some kind of dynamic resources compilation is introduced. I'm going to leave the question here for a future reference.